# on a Web Setup, how do I exclude all .pdb files?

Tags: file-handling, asp.net-3.5

In a sample solution on Visual Studio 2008, let's say, I have this:

- `myWebSite` project (*web site project*)
- `myLibrary` project (*library project*)
- `myWebsiteDeploy` project (*[web deployment project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx)*)
- `myWebSetup` project (*web setup project*)

inside `myWebSite` there is a `myLibrary.dll` and `myLibrary.pdb` witch they are included in the `myWebSiteDeploy` project and pass to the `myWebSetup`

**How can I tell** `myWebSeiteDeploy` or `myWebSetup` **to exclude all *.pdb files** as they are not needed in a deployed website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the project properties in Visual Studio. Select the "Build" tab, change your "Configuration" to "Release" and click on the "Advanced" button. **Change debug info to "none"**. Then the build will not create the .pdb files.

Comment: This does not work (as there is no such option) if it's a Website Project (the one that you can create a Deployable Version of the website so you can protect the source code of the website.